# Given a collection of intervals, merge all overlapping intervals

Tags: python

I m getting error as i m trying to solve this question. You are given the collection of interval and you have to merge the all overlapping intervals and return the new overlapped collection in 2D array.

```
class Solution(object):
def merge(self, intervals):

    finalList = []
    res = []
    x = 0
    y = 0
    a = 0
    b = 0

    if len(intervals) == 1 :
        return intervals

    for i in range(len(intervals)):
        for j in range(len(intervals[i])):

            if i < len(intervals) and j < len(intervals[i]) and i != len(intervals):

                x = intervals[i][len(intervals[i])-1]
                y = intervals[i+1][0]  ### I get error here (list index out of range)



                if x>=y:
                    a = intervals[i][0]
                    b = intervals[i+1][len(intervals[i])-1]

                    res = [a,b]
                    finalList.append(res)

                else:
                    a = intervals[i][0]
                    b = intervals[i][1]

                    res = [a,b]
                    finalList.append(res)
            else:
                break

    return finalList
```

Getting error !!
List index out of range

Comment: your index length should not be greater than `len(intervals)` where as you have `y = intervals[i+1][0]`

Answer (score 1):

You are getting an error because it fails when `i = len(intervals) - 1`. Suppose, your intervals is of size 4. The indices go like 0, 1, 2, 3. when `i = 3`, `i < len(intervals) and i != len(intervals)` all conditions are satisfied, but `i + 1` becomes 4, which becomes out of range. You should check for `i < len(intervals) - 1`. Also, if for loop goes in the range `len(intervals)`, then it is understood that `i < len(intervals)`, `j < len(intervals)[i]` and `i != len(intervals)`. You don't need to put an extra condition in if for this.